# how to pass string without double quotes inside mongodb query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to pass a string to my mongodb query, but when it goes inside the query it adds double quotes to the string.

I'm passing this as a string to the criteria, because it is formed dynamically as a string:

```
str1={AccId:8,WSId:24237,CaseID:{$in:[4697516]},MEId:{$in:[4697523]},ConfigID:{$‌​in:[4697520]}}

var criteria = { str1 },
```

So when I'm passing this final criteria to `db.coll.aggregate`, it appends `str1` and double quotes to the query.

```
query forming={"$match":{"str1":"{AccId:8,WSId:24237,CaseID:{$in:[4697516]},MEId:{$in:‌​[4697523]},ConfigID:{$in:[4697520]}}"}

 query desired= {"$match":{AccId:8,WSId:24237,CaseID:{$in:[4697516]},MEId:{$in:[4697523]},Config‌​ID:{$in:[4697520]}}}
```

How can I get the desired query ?

Comment: What you are trying to do with `criteria=([ {$match:criteria} ])` ?

Comment: Have you tried like `db.collname.aggregate([ {$match:criteria} ])` something like this?

Comment: oh sorry it is criteria1=([ {$match:criteria} ])

Comment: yes i have tried but it is adding double quotes to string criteria so when it is going inside aggregate query it is giving mongo error

Comment: `criteria` isn't a string in your example, so this doesn't make much sense. Can you [edit] your question to include a [MCVE]?

Comment: i have edited my question, let me know if you need any other inputs

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is create the pipeline using object initializing methods like the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). Also, there's no need to use the **[`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#in)** operator with a single array element in your query, just query the field directly on the value.

Follow this example to get the concept:

```
var criteria = {
        'AccId': 8,
        'WSId': 24237,
        'CaseID': 4697516,
        'MEId': 4697523,
        'ConfigID': 4697520
    },
    match = {};

match["$match"] = criteria;
db.collection.aggregate([match]);
```

Comment: i want to pass a string to this criteria, because that string is forming dynamically,
str1={AccId:8,WSId:24237,CaseID:{$in:[4697516]},MEId:{$in:[4697523]},ConfigID:{$in:[4697520]}}
 var criteria = {
     str1
    }, 
so when i m passing this final criteria to db.coll.aggregate, it appends str1 and double quotes to the desired query.

query forming={"$match":{"str1":"{AccId:8,WSId:24237,CaseID:{$in:[4697516]},MEId:{$in:[4697523]},ConfigID:{$in:[4697520]}}"}

query desired= {"$match":{AccId:8,WSId:24237,CaseID:{$in:[4697516]},MEId:{$in:[4697523]},ConfigID:{$in:[4697520]}}}

Comment: @ritika Thanks for the enlightenment but can you please add that info into your question not in the comments?

Comment: sure, i have added